# AzureException: Unable to access container using anonymous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration

Tags: azure, ubuntu-12.04, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to use Hadoop of Azure HDInsight. I am logging into the cluster by ssh and running the following

```
hadoop jar jar_name class_name wasb://container@storagename.core.windows.net/inputdir wasb://container@storagename.core.windows.net/outputdir
```

But I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Unable to access container
>   xxx in account yyy.core.windows.net using anonymous credentials, and
>   no credentials found for them  in the configuration.

I am using azure cli and I ran "azure login" before running the above mentioned hadoop job.

Please let me know how I can fix this error.

Ubuntu 12.04 runs on these machines.

PS: posted this on Azure forums as well, but reposting it here to get broader audience.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EDIT:
Your storage location should be wasb://container@storageacctname.blob.core.windows.net/inputdir

It sounds like your cluster is not attached to that storage account. Recreate your cluster and make sure that the account that holds the jar is attached to the cluster. Otherwise, move your jar to a storage account that is connected!

Comment: I am using the same storage but a different container from the one I specified during cluster creation time. I also created a public container within the same storage. I am unable to access this container as well using a command such as hdfs dfs -ls wasb://data2@dsparqstorage.core.windows.net where data2 is a public container.

Comment: Try hdfs dfs -ls wasb://data2@dsparqstorage.blob.core.windows.net

Comment: Sorry* hdfs dfs -ls wasb://data2@dsparqstorage.blob.core.windows.net/inputdir     You should always have your files in an input directory.

Comment: Problem is with the missing trailing '/'. There should be a / at the end.

Answer (score 4):

The correct format to use Azure Blob storage is

```
wasbs://<container>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<directory>/
```

Always make sure to end your wasbs with /

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been resolved and I am putting up the answer here in case someone faces the same issue.

I made couple of silly mistakes.

1) It should be wasb://@.blob.core.windows.net. I missed 'blob' earlier.
2) There should be a trailing '/'. So it should be hdfs dfs -ls wasb://data2@dsparqstorage.core.windows.net/

Comment: and you missed blob again in the last link

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error.

I used to write

```
wasb://directory/
```

instead of

```
wasb://container@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/directory/
```