# Error: E0902 - Unable to access container using anonymous credentials

Tags: azure, hadoop, hdfs, azure-hdinsight

I've created an HDInsight Linux-based cluster, connected to it through ssh, and running this command:

```
hadoop fs -ls wasb://defaultcontainer@myclusterstorage.blob.core.windows.net/
```

but the result is:

> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Unable to access container
>   defaultcontainer in account myclusterstorage.blob.core.windows.net
>   using anonymous credentials, and no credentials found for them  in the
>   configuration.

What can I do? The keys fs.defaultFS and fs.azure.account.key.myclusterstorage.blob.core.windows.net are exist in core-site.xml

(same error I get when I'm trying to run command "oozie job -config job.xml -run" from tutorial)

Comment: That issue is suspiciously similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601065/azureexception-unable-to-access-container-using-anonymous-credentials-and-no-c

Comment: I saw similar issue, and checked it. It is not the same, the other issue has been caused by wrong url

Comment: have you tried restarting hdfs?